# DotNetNuke 6 - Login 404 error after moving hosted site to local pc

Tags: localhost, dotnetnuke, transfer

All,

I have moved my hosted dnn 6 site to my local pc. Locally it pulls up fine and shows the home page and I can use the menu links and transition through various pages just fine. However, when I click log in I get a 404 page cannot be found. I am using a custom log in page and cannot figure out how to fix this locally. Basically I have a custom log in page set to secure on the hosted site so I can securely log in over https. I set is secure to true on the custom log in page and put the account log in control on it. I think this may have something to do with the 404 error I am getting on my localhost but cannot figure it out.

Can someone offer me a few suggestions on how to get this custom secure log in page to work locally on my pc? I am running windows 7 and iis 7.5. My alias for localhost/MySite is working fine - I can pull up the home page, click through links locally, etc. it is just the custom log in page gives me a 404 error locally.

thanks for any help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the issues is that your login page is accessing your local web server over port 443 for SSL and your web site is not configured to respond to that https request.

One thing you can probably do locally is just setup a self signed certificate.

Just Google for creating a self signed SSL certificate IIS 7.5 and you'll find plenty of examples.